# fontsize and enumitem failed in rmarkdown pdf

Tags: latex, r-markdown

My little rmarkdown example is as follows:

````
---
# documentclass: article
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
# linestretch: 1.5
fontsize: 18pt # 10pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum} 
  - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing #\singlespacing 
  - \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
  - \setlist{nosep}
  - \setlist{noitemsep}
  - \setcounter{enumi}{-1}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## random

\lipsum

## R Markdown

itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize 

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc

enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate 

1. uuu
1. vvv
1. www

why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why
````

I have two issues: changing `fontsize` from 10pt to 18pt is not working; commenting `\setlist{nosep}`, `\setlist{noitemsep}` and  `\setcounter{enumi}{-1}` or not makes no difference. Why these happen since this example is quite simple? (ps: `setspace` works well)

Comment: Please don't ask multiple  unrelated question in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`18pt` is not an allowed class option. With the default `article` class only a handful of normal sizes are defined. You can extent this by switching to the `extarticle` class which has the `17pt` option:

````
---
documentclass: extarticle
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
# linestretch: 1.5
fontsize: 17pt # 10pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum} 
  - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing #\singlespacing 
  - \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
  - \setlist{nosep}
  - \setlist{noitemsep}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## random

\lipsum

## R Markdown

itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize itemize 

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc

enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate enumerate 

1. uuu
1. vvv
1. www

why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why why
````

Comment: Sorry for late! Yes, your solution for `fontsize` works quite well! However, still don't know why `\setlist{nosep}\setlist{noitemsep}\setcounter{enumi}{-1}` didn't work! @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @JohnStone Ask about the enumitem problem in a separate question and best remove it from this one!